# JBOSS SSO Valve - Sessions not registered and therefore not invalidated on logout

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on

JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14)

I configured two wars with the SSO valve and the same security domain.

Logging in to one app also logs you in to the other as expected.

However if I log out from App 1 only that session is invalidated. As a result when I log back in as a different user, App 2 has the old data in its session.

I need to invalidate all sessions when I logout. That seems to be the intention of the code in the SingleSignOn valve. The method deregister(String ssoId) (which is called on logout) includes this bit of code:

```
    // Expire any associated sessions  
    Session sessions[] = sso.findSessions();  
    for (int i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {  
        // Remove from reverse cache first to avoid recursion  
        synchronized (reverse) {  
            reverse.remove(sessions[i]);  
        }  
        // Invalidate this session  
        sessions[i].expire();  
    }
```

The problem is that somehow the session from App 2 was not associated with the sso entry and it doesn't get invalidated here.

EDIT:

I have since found that the presence of the distributable tag in the war's web.xml causes the session to be passivated and on passivation the SSO Valve removes the session from the sso entry (sessionEvent method in SingleSignOn.java line 333). With the session removed from the sso entry it doesn't get invalidated when you logout. Not sure why the session needs to be removed from the sso entry on passivation.

SingleSignOne.java ln 333:

```
 // Was the session destroyed as the result of a timeout?
 // If so, we'll just remove the expired session from the
 // SSO.  If the session was logged out, we'll log out
 // of all session associated with the SSO.
 if (((session.getMaxInactiveInterval() > 0)
       && (System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastAccessedTimeInternal() >=
          session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000)) 
      || (Session.SESSION_PASSIVATED_EVENT.equals(event.getType()))) {
     removeSession(ssoId, session);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the distributable tag from the war's web.xml solved the problem for me.

If you do need your application to be clustered then using using clustered SSO should actually work ok.

What doesn't work is a clustered session (which is what the distributable tag does) with non-clustered sso.